# sort collection by specific type c#

Tags: c#, sorting, collections

I got a collection of scenarios (Enterprise Architect scenarios). Each scenario has a type and I want to loop through the collection by starting with a specific scenario.

The scenario I want to start the loop with has the type "Basic Path" and it contains some information about the other scenarios (which I think is a bug in enterprise architect but it's not relevant to this question. I just wanted to point out why I want to start with this scenario).

```
Collection scenarios = element.Scenarios;
//Sort the collection?

foreach (Scenario sc in scenarios)
{
    //Start with the scenario that has "Basic Path" type
}
```

The collection can have only one scenario with that type. How do I get the foreach statement to start with that scenario?

EDIT:
The order of the rest of the scenarios is irrelevant.

Comment: There seems to be two questions there - one about sorting, and one about skipping. Do you really want to sort AND skip?

Comment: I don't want to skip any scenario. I just want to loop through the collection starting with that scenario.

Comment: And thx to the guy that downvoted without a comment. That is definitely the way people learn to ask better questions..

Comment: But what does that mean? Suppose that the starting scenario is at index 10, and there are 15 items in the collection. Does that mean you want to access the elements in the order `10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` ? If not, then exactly HOW do you want the elements to be ordered?

Comment: That is exactly what I want. The order of the rest is irrelevant cause the only reason I want to start with that specific element is that it contains information about the others.

Comment: I've updated my answer below using this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little sparse, and I'm not quite sure which collection type you're using (you should change to use a generically typed one, though). But something like this would work.

```
Collection scenarios = element.Scenarios
                              .Cast<Scenario>()
                              .OrderBy(c => c.type == "Basic Path" ? 0 : 1);

foreach (Scenario sc in scenarios)
{
    //Start with the scenario that has "Basic Path" type
}
```

This will sort the elements by assigning them with a sorting value of `0` when the type is "Basic Path" or `1` otherwise. Thus, they will show up first.

Although I don't know why you'd want a `foreach` that iterates over types that need to be in a certain order, like this. There are certainly times for that, but this feels like a messy implementation.

Alternatively, since you say there's only one, you could single it out by doing this.

```
var BasicPath = element.Scenarios
                       .Cast<Scenario>()
                       .SingleOrDefault(c => c.type == "Basic Path");
```

You could also just use `FirstOrDefault`, if multiple being returned isn't indicative of corrupt data.

Then you could iterate the others with this.

```
foreach (var v in element.Scenarios.Cast<Scenario>().Where(c => c.type != "Basic Path"))
{
    // definitely not the same as that first one.
}
```

Comment: It's an Enterprise Architect Collection. I think the type is IDualCollection.

Comment: @n.Stenvang Alright, well regardless, if I'm understanding you correctly, one of those should do what you want.

Comment: I've tried to implement both suggestions and they both work as intended. Thx for answering - Upvoted!
It seems like I could use some tutorials on this topic.

Comment: @n.Stenvang Glad to be of assistance. For what it's worth, this solution uses LINQ. You might want to read up a bit on that and how you can leverage it. I'm sure MSDN has some good articles on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to reorder them according to your specifications. Or have element.Scenarios be some of your specific collection and implement it the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make your type a class rather than a string and give it a property representing the sequence in which you want to process the items. So 'Basic Type' might have a sequence of 1. Then you could order your query by this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a combination of `SkipWhile()` and `TakeWhile()`, where both use the same predicate.

Here's an example with an integer list (for simplicity):

```
IEnumerable<int> sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, 15);

Func<int, bool> predicate = x => x != 10;

var result = 
    sequence.SkipWhile(predicate)
    .Concat(sequence.TakeWhile(predicate));

// This prints
// 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

For your example, it might look something like:

```
Func<Scenario, bool> predicate = s => s.Type != "Basic Path";

var sequence = 
    scenarios.SkipWhile(predicate)
    .Concat(scenarios.TakeWhile(predicate));
```

Comment: Getting the following error:
Instance argument: cannot convert from 'EA.Collection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EA.Scenario>'

Answer (score 0):

You can't enumerate the IEnumerable collection starting with special instance before ordering it.
If you do not want to order collection, there is other way:

```
var bpScenario = element.Scenarios.First(o=> {your condition to get your "Basci Path"(what is it? Is this Type or field value or what?)});
//
// here process your "Basic Path" scenario
//
foreach(var scenario in element.Scenarios.Where(o=> {condition where not "Basic Path" scenario}))
{
// process your other scenarios
}
```